# How do I style a link inside a specific div tag?

Tags: html, css, sass

So, I have the following scss which is supposed to target the links inside the class called categories, however only the :hover section is styles but the normal link is getting it's colors from the parent of the categories class and is not getting overridden by the scss I have written. What did I do wrong?

```css
.categories {
  a{
    color: #767676;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  a:hover{
    color: #767676;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
}
```

```php
<div class="col col-8">
  @foreach ($allStories as $stories)
  <div class="row py-2 pl-3">       
    <div class="col-12 news p-0">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="" class="p-0 newsImage">
      <div class="px-2 py-4 headers">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <strong>
            <a href="{{ route('NewsFlashesController.show', $stories->id) }}">{{ $stories->title }}
            </a>
          </strong>
        </div>
        {{-- <div class="col-6 text-right">
          <img src="{{ asset('images/like-2.svg')}}" alt="" width="15px">
            <span class="previewText" style="vertical-align: middle;">{{ $stories->likes }}
          </span> &nbsp&nbsp
          <img src="{{ asset('images/chat.svg')}}" alt="" width="15px">
            <span class="previewText" style="vertical-align: middle;">10 
          </span>
        </div> --}}
        </div>
        <div class="row categories">
          <a href="#" class="ml-3">
            <small>{{ $stories->category->name }}</small>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <span class=" pl-3 pr-2 pb-2 previewText">
            @if(strlen($stories->story) > 180)
            {{ substr($stories->story, 0, 180) }}...
            @else
            {{ $stories->story }}
            @endif
          </span>            
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  @endforeach          

</div>
```

```css
.categories a {
  color: #767676;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.categories a:hover {
  color: #767676;
}
```

```html
<div class="col col-8">
    <div class="row py-2 pl-3">       
    <div class="col-12 news p-0">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="" class="p-0 newsImage">
      <div class="px-2 py-4 headers">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <strong>
            <a href="http://dechra.test/viewstory/1">A long post
            </a>
          </strong>
        </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row categories">
          <a href="#" class="ml-3">
            <small>Interviews </small>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <span class=" pl-3 pr-2 pb-2 previewText">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc volutpat tellus sed sagittis interdum. Fusce auctor tortor in orci condimentum, ut pretium ante dictum. Proin et rutru...
                      </span>            
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: add your working HTML & CSS

Comment: Can you post the corresponding HTML and any SCSS that appies to the surrounding HTML?

Comment: Added the other parts

Comment: There is probably a more specific rule being applied - inspect the element and look at the classes applied to it - you'll see yours being crossed out and the ones that appear first are the ones you need to override.

Comment: Thanks Sean, got it now

Comment: If your problem was solved do not forget to close this question